# Unresolved dependency when directive is minified

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I have a directive that is working when the application is not minified

Once I minify it I get an error

```
Unknown provider: tProvider <- t <- dateTimeFilterDirective
```

Is there a way to have the directive working when minified?

```
module bundledAppModule {
'use strict';

export class ngDateTimeFilterDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    static $inject = ['$filter'];
    // static $inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$ngModel', '$filter'];
    public static className = 'dateTimeFilter';
    public restrict: string;
    public require: string;
    public priority: number;
    public link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn;

    constructor($filter: ng.IFilterService) {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.require = 'ngModel';
        this.priority = 1;

        this.link = ($scope: ng.IScope, $element: JQuery, $attrs: any, $ngModel: ng.INgModelController) => {
            $ngModel.$formatters.push((modelValue) => {
                console.log('ngDateTimeFilterDirective', modelValue);


                return new Date($filter('date')(modelValue, 'medium'));
            });
        };
    }

    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        var directive = ($filter: ng.IFilterService) => {
            return new ngDateTimeFilterDirective($filter);
        };
        return directive;
    }
};
```

}

**EDIT:**

The error happens because of the dependency $filter: ng.IFilterService. Once I remove it all is working in minified and unminified versions. But I need the filter and have no idea how to make it working after minification. I know that I have to speciy dependencies 2 time for controllers to make them work after minification so I guess I am missing that part but adapted for directives.

This is the stack trace - minified :-)
[image]

This is how I use the directive.

```
<div ng-app="bundledApp" ng-controller="bundledController">
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="someDate" date-time-filter />
{{someDate}}
<input type="button" ng-click="setDate();" value="changedate">
</div>
```

The error happens during initialization of the app. When I click afterwards a button the controller action is invoked but the directive is not hit (no console log message)

Comment: where are you getting the error? by looking at the code I don't think it would be here, but rather where it is used. Most likely a missing explicit dependency declaration.

Comment: actually, you only need to define the $filter in the $inject variable. In that place you should only define the ones injected in the constructor. The link function has a fixed set of dependencies you can't inject them.

Comment: regarding your edit. you most likely get the $scope in the $filter variable in constructor. that might be causing the crash

Comment: I removed the unneccessary values from the  $inject variable. It did still work in unminified version but not in minified version.

Comment: where exactly is the error? can you post a stack trace?

Comment: I posted the stack trace.

Comment: Consider using `ng-strict-di` to get useful debugging info to assist in tracking down the root of this problem. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-app Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `$inject` property to the instantiated directive function:

```
public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
    var directive = ($filter: ng.IFilterService) => {
        return new ngDateTimeFilterDirective($filter);
    };
    //INJECT $filter dependence
    directive.$inject = ['$filter'];
    return directive;
}
```